# PidlidPrivate in MAPI will not hide the message

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-2019

I am checking PidlidPrivate property in MAPI.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidprivate-canonical-property, this property can hide the message.

So I use MFCMAPI to set the value of PidlidPrivate property to True. But that does not work. The message will always show.

I test in Outlook 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the message will not be hidden. It is only applicable to appointments from other user's calendars - if an appointment is marked as private, Outlook won't show its details (only start/duration). All of its properties are still accessible through MAPI.

If you want a message to be invisible to an end user, create a hidden (associated) item. Outlook Object Model exposes messages like that through `MAPIFolder.GetStorage`. You can see these messages in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click IMAPIFolder button and go to the "Associated Contents" tab. It will also let you edit MAPI properties (click IMessage button, double click on a property, etc.)